# React почему не работают хуки?

Tags: reactjs

Счетчик не увеличивается, вообще ничего не происходит, так же с другими хуками пробовал. Версия react 17.0.1

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
    
const app = (      
    <App /> 
);

function App() {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

    return (
        <div>
            <p>Вы кликнули {count} раз</p>
            <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
                Нажми на меня
            </button>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;

if (document.getElementById("app")) {
    ReactDOM.render(app, document.getElementById("app"));
}
```

Comment: И никакой ошибки нет?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-payne-k96n2?file=/src/App.js
Все работает. Скорее всего у Вас где-то ошибка в другом месте.

Comment: В коде ошибок не вижу, что-то вы делаете не так значит.

Comment: Да у меня вообще кнопки не работают, я пытаюсь привязать console.log к кнопке, даже он не вызывается, напимер onClick={upPage} в атрибутах, ну и функцию с e.preventDefault(); console.log('123')

Comment: Можете воспроизвести вашу проблему на codesandbox.io ?

Comment: Я отпусти версию react c 17.0.1 до "react": "^16.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.2.0", и все заработало

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте удалить папку node_modules и еще раз запустить команду `npm i && npm start`